# How to solve the question related to differentiation.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

**The question is** :

Find the point of differentiability of the function $f : \mathbb {R} \longrightarrow \mathbb {R}$ defined by $f(x) = |x - x^3|$.

Please help me.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Find the derivatives at $x=0,\pm1$

Comment: By "point of differentiability", I think you mean instead "all points where $f$ is differentiable". What have you tried? It's quite obvious if you draw a picture: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Abs%5Bx-x%5E3%5D

Comment: What @labbhattacharjee means is *find the derivatives from the left and the right at $x=0,\pm 1$ and show they are not equal.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $x-x^3=x(1-x^2)=0$ for $x=0,\pm1$.

The derivative fails to exist at $x=0,\pm1$.

For $x>1$, we find $f(x)=x^3-x$ and $f'(x)=3x^2-1$.

For $0<x<1$, $f(x)=x-x^3$ and $f'(x) =1-3x^2$.

For $-1<x<0$, $f(x)=x^3-x$ and $f'(x)=3x^2-1$.

For $x<-1$, $f(x)=x-x^3$ and $f'(x)=1 -3x^2$.

Therefore, we have

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}3x^2-1&,x>1\\\\
1-3x^2&,0<x<1\\\\
3x^2-1&,-1<x<0\\\\
1-3x^2&,x<-1\end{cases}$$

To see clearly the failure of existence of $f'(0)$ and $f'(\pm1)$, note that

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|h-h^3|}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|h|}{h}|1-h^2|$$

does not exist since the limits from the right-hand side and left-hand side are not equal.

Answer (score 2):

We know the function $|y|$ is differentiable everywhere except at $0$, where the left hand derivative is not equal to the right hand derivative.

The function $x-x^3$ is a polynomial and hence is differentiable everywhere.

Thus, in order to see where $|x-x^3|$ is *not* differentiable, it suffices to find at which points $x-x^3$ becomes zero. This happens when $x$ is $0$, $1$ or $-1$. At these points, we can find the right hand and left hand derivatives of $f$ and see that they are unequal.

Thus, $f$ is differentiable everywhere except $0$, $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: It is not clear from your argument why the function is not differentiable at $0$ and $\pm 1$. The implication "$g$ differentiable at $x$, $f$ not differentiable at $g(x)$" --> "$f \circ g$ not differentiable at $x$" is false (e.g. $g(x) = x^2$ and $f(y) = |y|$ at $x=0$)

Comment: That's right, I overlooked it. Edited my answer.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll leave my comment, even though you have amended your answer. It just seems like an issue that is worth pointing out.

Comment: Yeah, definitely!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $$f\left( x \right) =\left| x \right| $$ is not differentiable at the point $x=0$

Answer (score 0):

Get intuition by drawing a graphical representation (see below): the values of $x$ for which there is no differentiability are the values of x with "angular points" on the curve (left derivative $\neq$ right derivative).

[image]